# can't use document.write when setting interval?

Tags: javascript

This is the code that works by displaying as a clock:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    setInterval(getCurrentDateTime, 1000);

    function getCurrentDateTime() {

        document.getElementById("timeDiv").innerHTML = new Date();
    }
</script>
```

But I don't understand why if I use :

```
document.write(new Date());
```

then the page doesn't work as a clock? I just rewrite page every second, which should work too...

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```js
setInterval(getCurrentDateTime, 1000);

function getCurrentDateTime() {
  document.body.innerHTML = new Date();
}
```

Comment: op knows it, but why does `document.write` not work after loading?